# How to assign not-PDF file by digital certificate?

Tags: digital-signature, file-types

XML, EPUB, etc. formats need also to be signed by digital certificate, like in the [PDF's certificate-based signatures](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/certificate-based-signatures.html). There are **reliable** open-standards and open-source software to accomplish it?

PS: there are a lot of resources in the Web about PDF, but I not see the analog resources about "not PDF files".

Comment: GPG is often [used for this](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html).

Comment: Hi @AndrolGenhald, thanks, good clue (!), it is 100% compatible with the PDF's standards?  That is, if I assign a PDF with this Gnu instructions, the assigned PDF file will be accept by the Adobe's signature software?  There are a link describing/endorsing **interoperability** of the GNU procedures with commercial/official implementations?

Comment: That question would sound better if was asked the other way around: is Adobe's PDF signature thingy in any way compatible with general-purpose file-signing tools? (I don't know the answer but I'm guessing it's not)

Comment: A similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407523/how-to-add-digital-signature-rsa-certificate-etc-to-any-of-file-using-php (question was about PHP, but the answers contain generally useful information, not much PHP code)

Comment: ... For EPUB seems [v3.1 Specification/Digital Signatures File](http://www.idpf.org/epub/31/spec/epub-ocf.html#sec-container-metainf-signatures.xml)... But there are no PGP, only integrity checksum.

Comment: Hi @WumpusQ.Wumbley, thanks (!), other question is perhaps a solution for my problem... Please help me to express in better English an objective question at https://security.stackexchange.com/q/187083/140435